# SQL query for many to many exclusive IN query

Tags: sql, oracle, many-to-many, sqlplus

I have a table Table1 with columns A and B (many to many table).

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|       ColumnA       |      ColumnB     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          a1         |         b1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          a1         |         b2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          a2         |         b1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          a2         |         b3       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          a3         |         b2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want a list of `A`s whose `B`s are ONLY in list of `B`s.

So, from above table, if list is `[b1, b2]`

**Expected** `[a1, a3]`
Not including `a2`as it is associated with `b3` also.

Comment: You are asking for a pure SQL query, `spring-data-jpa` tag is irrelevant with the question I think

Comment: It asked for 5 tags. I was out of options. :-)

Comment: It's not mandatory to use 5 tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and having:

```
select a
from ab
group by a
having sum(case when b not in ('b1', 'b2') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause is checking the number of rows that are *not* in the list.  The `= 0` says there are none.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are not any nulls in `ColumnB` you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where not exists (select 1 from tablename where ColumnA = t.ColumnA and ColumnB not in ('b1', 'b2'))
```

If you want only the distinct values of `ColumnA`:

```
select distinct t.ColumnA
from tablename t
where not exists (select 1 from tablename where ColumnA = t.ColumnA and ColumnB not in ('b1', 'b2'))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=73685bfdfc79f5ed56f583cdca7c0635).